# How to control the links in webview

Tags: android

i have a problem with my webview app. I would like to open all external links in default browser but keep internal link opened in webview.
Actually i have done all my best but both the internal and external links rather open in default browser instead of opening only the external links in the default browser.

Below is my code. Please kindly suggest me a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://www.Example.com")) {
                    return false;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

    });
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.Example.com");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                if (url.startsWith("your-domain") || url.contains("your-domain")) {
                    // internal links... (open in same view)
                    view.loadUrl(url);       
                } else {
                    // external links... (open in default browser)
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This code is better, but i dont want to specify external-domain.  I just want every external link to open with default browser. please could you fiddle the code a bit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you sir, you actually made my day. In fact i have been searching for the solution for two consecutive days. Sir, the [getUrl] indicate some notice: "Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19 ): andoid.webkit.WebResourceRequest#getUrl.....
" . What do you think about it? Thank you once again.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code will help you.

```
String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "http"
String host = data.getHost(); // "twitter.com"
```

From building a Single String as below and comparing will achieve your requirement.

```
String weburl  = scheme+host;

@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Uri data = Uri.parse(url);
    String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "http"
    String host = data.getHost(); // "twitter.com"
            String weburl  = scheme+host;
    if (weburl.equals("https://www.Example.com")) {
                return false;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Sir could you enlighten me more. I am not that good in app development. kindly tell me how and where to place the code. Thank you.

Comment: It still cant open the internal links in the webview.